# How to parse json payload in html form formate to an api in django and perform calculation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to parse the The parameters below to an endpoint for payment and upon a successful payment, the amount added to a a model field in my database. Parameters are " merchant_id, transaction_id, amount, API_Key, apiuser, email, redirect_url "      and the api " https://test.theteller.net "

I have a model that i want the amount enter by a user to be save to the vote filed upon successful payment.

model.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
  Award = models.ForeignKey(Award, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  category = models.CharField(max_length=100,)
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.category



class Nomination(models.Model):
  Fullname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  Nominee_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nominations_images')
  slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



  def __str__(self):
       return self.Fullname
```

View.py

```
     class NominationView(ListView):
       model = Category
       template_name = 'nomination.html'


   class NominationPayView(DetailView):
      model = Nomination
      template_name = 'Payment.html'
```

Payment.html

```html
<form action="https://test.theteller.net " method="post">
  <input type="text" name="merchant_id" id="merchant_id" value="">
  <input type="text" name="transaction_id" id="transaction_id" value="{{nomination.Nominee_ID }}" >
  ...
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

AM processing the form on the detailView because i want the amount saved to the element being viewed.

1. I would like to pass the parameters to the API endpoint successfully.
2. Then save the amount to vote field in the nomination upon success response from the API. Any help.

Comment: Typo: `post="post"` should be `method="post"`

Comment: @ – Barmar  corrected

Comment: Was that just a copying error, or was it in the original code? It could have been the reason for the problem.